# Scala dispatcher-worker actor pattern

Tags: scala, actor, dispatcher

I am trying to design a dispatcher-worker actor pattern for Scala using the standard scala.actors package.

The dispatcher receives work from a `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue` and sends it out to worker actors to be processed. When all of the work is done the dispatcher should tell each of the workers to quit and then it should also quit. Here is the code I came up with, but it hangs when all of the work is done (I think there are pending `'GiveMeWork` messages in the dispatcher's queue):

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
import scala.actors.Actor

object Dispatcher
extends Actor {
  println("Dispatcher created")

  def act() {
    val workers = (1 to 4).map(id => (new Worker(id)).start())

    loop {
      react {
        case 'GiveMeWork =>
          // println("Worker asked for work")
          val (time, i) = workQueue.take()
          if (time == 0) {
            println("Quitting time")
            workers.foreach(_ !? 0L)
          } else {
            println("Arrival at dispatcher: i: " + i + " dispatch time: " +
                    time + ", elapsed: " + (System.nanoTime() - time))
            sender ! time
          }
        case 'Quit =>
          println("Told to quit")
          sender ! 'OffDuty
          exit()
      }
    }
  }
}

class Worker(id: Int)
extends Actor {
  println("Worker(" + id + ") created")
  var jobs = 0

  def act() {
    Dispatcher ! 'GiveMeWork

    loop {
      react {
        case time: Long =>
          if (time == 0) {
            println("Worker(" + id + ") completed " + jobs + " jobs")
            sender ! 'OffDuty
            exit()
          } else {
            println("Arrival at worker(" + id + "): dispatch time: " +
                    time + ", elapsed: " + (System.nanoTime() - time))
            Thread.sleep(id)
            jobs += 1
            Dispatcher ! 'GiveMeWork
          }
      }
    }
  }
}

val workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue[(Long, Int)](1000)

Dispatcher.start()

for (i <- 0 until 5000) {
  Thread.sleep(1)
  workQueue.put((System.nanoTime(), i))
}

workQueue.put((0L, 0))

println("Telling Dispatcher to quit")
Dispatcher !? 'Quit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a race:

```
val (time, i) = workQueue.take()
```

All the work is done, including `workQueue.put((0L, 0))`, so it will wait forever.

It's a bad idea to use different types of concurrency simultaneously.

Dispatcher can inform task source about task limit:

```
import scala.actors.{Actor, OutputChannel}
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

case class Task(time: Long, i: Int)
case object GiveMeWork
case object Quit
case object OffDuty

object Dispatcher extends Actor {
  println("Dispatcher created")

  def act() {
    val workers = (1 to 4).map(id => (new Worker(id)).start())
    val waitingWorkers = Queue[OutputChannel[Any]](workers: _*)
    val tasks = Queue[Task]()
    var workSender: Option[OutputChannel[Any]] = None

    loop {
      react {
        case GiveMeWork =>
          if (!tasks.isEmpty) sender ! tasks.dequeue()
          else waitingWorkers enqueue sender

          workSender map { _ ! GiveMeWork }
          workSender = None
        case t: Task =>
          if (!waitingWorkers.isEmpty) waitingWorkers.dequeue() ! t
          else tasks enqueue t

          if (tasks.length < 1000) sender ! GiveMeWork
          else workSender = Some(sender)
        case Quit =>
          println("Told to quit")
          workers.foreach{ _ ! Quit }
          sender ! OffDuty
          exit()
      }
    }
  }
}

class Worker(id: Int)
extends Actor {
  var jobs = 0

  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case t: Task =>
          Thread.sleep(id)
          jobs += 1
          Dispatcher ! GiveMeWork
        case Quit =>
          println("Worker(" + id + ") completed " + jobs + " jobs")
          sender ! OffDuty
          exit()
      }
    }
  }
}

Dispatcher.start()

for (i <- 0 until 5000) {
  Thread.sleep(1)
  Dispatcher !? Task(System.nanoTime(), i)
}

println("Telling Dispatcher to quit")
Dispatcher !? Quit
```

Comment: I do not like using the LinkedBlockingQueue, but I need to limit the maximum number of processes waiting to execute. When I used this pattern in real code, I got an out-of-memory error because the method generating the work (a directory recursive descent), added files faster than they could be processed. Any suggestions for how to do it purely with actors?